# VMWare Mountain Lion 10.8.3 (AMD) freezes at load after installing VMWare tools

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, vmware-workstation

I had a perfectly working Mac OS 10.8.3 image for AMD in which I developed a quietly big app for iPhone. Don't know why, but today I tried installing VMWare tools because somebody was promising more performance with it and additional features like folder sharing between guest and host systems.

Now my loading stops right before the desktop should appear because the mouse cursor becomes a little black square (and it was always like that right before loading the desktop). Randomly the wheel may spin for 2 or 3 times and than again stop (I awaited for 30 minutes to see may be it boots in the end).

Is there a quick fix? I cannot afford loosing what I did there. 
As a backup I'll just open the vdmk and copy, but I would like to may be fix this broken image.

Answer (score 1):

One of Apple's conditions in the OS X EULA is that running OS X in a VM is only supported on Apple hardware. To comply with the license, VMware has added checks that will detect and stop OS X VMs from running if VMware's software detects the host hardware is not made by Apple.

It may be that installing the VMware tools reinstated or reactivated that hardware check and is preventing the VM from successfully running.

Comment: I happened to do the same and had to restore my machine to a previous running state to enable VM.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for that. I solved my problem doing the following:

- After install the Mac os, make a snapshot for safety
- You should insert the darwin(VMWare tools) iso and install it.
- After install the VMware tools, don't reboot. Just leave the screen open.
- Navigate(via terminal) as root ("sudo su") mode to /Library > Application Support > VMware Tools.
- Delete vmmemctl.kext and vmmemctl
- Edit the file **services.sh** in the same directory
- Comment those both line in that file, leave them just like below

  - ## kextload '/Library/Application Support/VMware Tools/vmmemctl.kext'
  - ## '/Library/Application Support/VMware Tools/vmmemctl'
- Save the edited file, quit the editor, and now (via the still-running Installer) reboot the virtual machine.

It might take a long time to boot

**solution found in the robservatory blog([link](http://www.robservatory.com/?p=809))**

I did not found the solution myself. The credit is all for robservatory.

Comment: Since external sources can disappear, can you provide instructions in your answer?